# jQuery loop through multiple items on page

Tags: jquery

So I have a page running countdown scripts in a table based on the time inside of a hidden input.

Each input has an individual id of "id="time_x" where x increases from 1.

Each on then runs the timer into a div .

My Question is how do I loop and select through a list of the inputs so that each input is able to feed the id to the jquery function which calls the timer.

Eg

```
<input ..... id="time_1" value="1000"/>
<input ..... id="time_2" value="2000" />
```

how can I select through all the inputs, get the value and then pass it to the right divs.

Thanks

Comment: Err... What? Could you explain this better or post some code?

Comment: Hmm.. post your code so that we could understand the context

Comment: A special class would be "easier" than such ids, but `$("[id^=time_]").each(function(){ ... });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a new element class for each one:

```
<input class="item" id="time_1" value="1000"/>
<input class="item" id="time_2" value="2000"/>
<input class="item" id="time_3" value="3000"/>

$.each($('.item'),function(){
 console.log($(this).attr('id')); 
});
```

or if you want to catch the input value is more easier:

```
$.each($('.item'),function(){
     console.log($(this).attr("value"));
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$('input').each(function(v,i){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

NOTE: this will loop through all the inputs in the douments.. its better to give class to all the input you want to loop through and get its id

Answer (score 1):

You can select all the inputs with an id of that form using `$('[id^=time_]')` as described in  http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

You could call a function on these using `.each()` and you could get the ID of the current one by using `this` from inside the loop.

For a more specific answer you might need to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

A non-jQuery solution:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
id;

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
    id = inputs[i].id;

    if (id.indexOf('time_') == 0) {
        id = id.substr(5);
        // do stuff with id and inputs[i].value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "Start With" selector:

```
$('input[id^="time"]').each(function() {
   var value = $(this).val(); //get value

   //now get right div and inject value
   $(this).next('div').text(value);       
});
```